# When mount a host symlink to container, is it possible not to dereference it?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

On the host there is a symlink file "/etc/link" which point to "/root/file",

lrwxrwxrwx /etc/link -> /root/file

Run the following command to start a container:

docker run -d -v /etc/link:/etc/link nginx:1.0.0

, dockerd would dereference the symlink and mount "/root/file" to the container, "/etc/link" in container is a regular file, not a symlink. but what I really want is to let /etc/link in the container be the original symlink file, so I run cat /etc/link in the container, it would print the content of container file "/root/file", not the file on the host.

I know this can be achived by mounting the whole /etc directory, but it's not acceptable in my case.

Comment: Good question. I don't believe it's possible. Probably easier to inject something like this as a configuration of the application.